# Stacked barchart over work week and another group

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I have several criteria from which I want to create a stacked barchart.

My criteria are:
work week, quantity, customer, Tag (Received, Shipped)

This (facet_grid(~Tag)) looks ok but is not really what I need.

```
ggplot(allRecords, aes(x = reorder(WW,Date), y = Quantity, fill = 
Customer)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", colour = "black") + 
facet_grid(~Tag) +
labs(x = "Work Week") + 
ggtitle("Goods last 3 months by core customers") +
theme_bw()
```

I need a stacked chart for "received" and "shipped" for each work week by customer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you able to make some sample/dummy data that works with the plot you have? It doesn't have to be many rows, just a small set of data that can be used to test solutions

Comment: Hi, Stacked Bar charts are often a pain to build, usually requiring pivoting the data (dplyr::gather). How do you want the output chart to look (x, y, group, color, etc)?

Comment: My x-axis is the work week, the stacked bar is the count of goods for each customer. I already have the chart via facet_grid(~Tag) but I need for each work week a stacked bar for received and a stacked bar for shipped goods. If you run the code above with the sample rows, you will see what I mean. Sorry, don't know how to describe it in a better way.

Comment: I understand this - In your sample chart, received and shipped are facet'ed, and customers are stacked by week - but instead you want received and shipped stacked by week. In the end three stacks (1 for each week) for each customer.

Comment: ggplot(allRecords, aes(x = reorder(WW,Date), y = Quantity, fill = Tag)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", colour = "black") + 
  facet_grid(~Customer)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is a good view at the data too. I don't want the facetting, I need for each work week two stacked charts, one for shipped, one for received. All in one graph.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample rows:

WW <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)

Quantity <- c(12,23,12,34,56,23,10,11,23)

Date <- lubridate::ymd_hms(c("2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-09 15:49:41", "2019-01-09 15:49:4", "2019-01-09 15:49:4", "2019-01-16 09:53:56", "2019-01-16 09:53:56", "2019-01-16 09:53:56"))

Customer <- c("C1", "C2", "Other","C1", "C2", "Other","C1", "C2", "Other")

Tag <- as.factor(c("Received", "Received", "Shipped", "Shipped", "Received", "Received", "Shipped", "Received", "Received"))

records <- data.frame(WW, Quantity, Date, Customer, Tag)

Comment: You can make data.frame without  intermediate var:    allRecords <- data.frame(
  WW = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  Quantity = c(12,23,12,34,56,23,10,11,23),
  Date = lubridate::ymd_hms(c("2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-09 15:49:41", "2019-01-09 15:49:4", "2019-01-09 15:49:4", "2019-01-16 09:53:56", "2019-01-16 09:53:56", "2019-01-16 09:53:56")),
  Customer = c("C1", "C2", "Other","C1", "C2", "Other","C1", "C2", "Other"),
  Tag = as.factor(c("Received", "Received", "Shipped", "Shipped", "Received", "Received", "Shipped", "Received", "Received"))
)

Comment: you can make week easier like this -- WW = lubridate::week(c("2019-01-03 10:07:31", ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
ggplot(records, aes(x = reorder(WW,Date), y = Quantity, fill = 
                         Tag)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", colour = "black") + 
  facet_grid(~Customer) +
  labs(x = "Work Week") + 
  ggtitle("Goods last 3 months by core customers") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

data

```
allRecords <- data.frame( 
    Quantity = c(12,23,12,34,56,23,10,11,23), 
    WW = lubridate::week(c("2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-03 10:07:31", "2019-01-09 15:49:41", "2019-01-09 15:49:4", "2019-01-09 15:49:4", "2019-01-16 09:53:56",     "2019-01-16 09:53:56", "2019-01-16 09:53:56")), 
    Customer = c("C1", "C2", "Other","C1", "C2", "Other","C1", "C2", "Other"), 
    Tag = as.factor(c("Received", "Received", "Shipped", "Shipped", "Received", "Received", "Shipped", "Received", "Received")) 
)
```

code

```
ggplot(allRecords, aes(x = Tag, y = Quantity, fill = Customer)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", colour = "black") + 
  facet_grid(~WW) +
  labs(x = "Work Week") + 
  ggtitle("Goods last 3 months by core customers") +
  theme_bw()
```

output

[image: stacked bar chart]